# Building zsh without admin priv: No terminal handling library found

Tags: zsh, compiling

I am trying to install Zsh without root privileges on a Linux machine. I downloaded the source tarball and run:

```
./configure --prefix=<my_installation_path>
```

but then I got:

> configure: error: "No terminal handling library was found on your
>   system. This is probably a library called curses or ncurses. You may
>   need to install a package called 'curses-devel' or 'ncurses-devel' on
>   your system"

### Installing ncurses:

Since I am not root on this system, I downloaded `ncurses` and installed it manually (also using `./configure --prefix=<my_installation_path>`), which seems to have gone well.

I then updated the following paths:

```
INSTALLATION_PATH='/path/to/installation'
export PATH=$INSTALLATION_PATH/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INSTALLATION_PATH/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CFLAGS=-I$INSTALLATION_PATH/include
```

and tried installing Zsh again, but got the same `ncurses` error. As far as I can tell, the path variables above point to the right locations, and I can check this on the shell. Why is Zsh not recognizing `ncurses?`

Comment: Can't you get an admin to install these things on your machine? These packages would be available for any distribution.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I don't have admin privileges - The goal is to install it without them.

Comment: I know you don't, but isn't there someone who does? You could certainly install with one, but you're just going to create a mess, especially if there are a lot of packages you are trying to install that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

Following Gilles' answer, I updated `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` and the problem goes away during `configure`.

However, I now get an error during `make`:

```
<INSTALLATION_PATH>/lib/libncurses.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also get a `recompile with -fPIC`. I guess this refers to the compilation of `ncurses`. I presume this means that I built `ncurses` as static, and I should built it as dynamic? How would I do that?

### Update 2:

I re-compiled `ncurses` again. This time, I did:

- `export CXXFLAGS=" -fPIC"`
- `export CFLAGS=" -fPIC"`

prior to `make`, and then added `--enable-shared` to `./configure` for both `ncurses` and `Zsh`. This seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: I also met with this issue. The solution here works for me.

Comment: Using "--with-shared" worked for me. See ./configure --help will tell you what is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I see at least one thing missing: you're passing `CFLAGS=-I/path/to/installation/include`, which lets the compilation scripts find the header files, but you also need to let the compilation scripts find the library to link against (`libncurses.a`). Also the installation instructions say to use `CPPFLAGS` for the include directories, not `CFLAGS`.

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I$INSTALLATION_PATH/include" LDFLAGS="-L$INSTALLATION_PATH/lib"
```

Be sure to read the complete error messages from `./configure`, and check the logs in `config.log` which contain more information (there's a detailed transcript of the commands that `configure` ran and their output).

Comment: Thank you @Gilles. That fixed the problem that I reported. However I now get `<INSTALLATION_PATH>/lib/libncurses.a: could not read symbols: Bad value` **during make**. Not sure why. I am using the latest stable releases of both, and did not see any problems during the installation of `ncourses`.

Comment: I also get a `recompile with -fPIC`. I wonder if this is why I get the error that I get.